# Russian character and alphanumeric converter

Tags: php, regex

How can I remove non-alphanumeric characters from a string in PHP while keeping Russian characters like `ч` and `г`?

I tried to translate the string and then clean it with `preg_replace`, but this would remove the Russian characters.

Comment: What do you mean by clean? Provide before & after strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `preg_replace`. You just have to build a regular expression that matches what you desire.

If I understood your question correctly, this should work:

`preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $string);`

Brief explanation:

- `^` matches any character that is not in this set.
- `\p{L}` matches any letter (including the Cyrillic alphabet).
- `\p{N}` matches any number.
- `\s` matches any whitespaces.
- `/u` adds Unicode support.

If you **only** want to match letters from the Cyrillic alphabet., you may want to use `\p{Cyrillic}` instead of `\p{L}`.